# Reinitialize autocomplete after form submission

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, tom-select, symfonyux

I have a custom [autocomplete](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-autocomplete/current/index.html) input that is not bound to any entities:

```
$builder
    ->add('input', TextType::class, [
        'autocomplete' => true,
        'autocomplete_url' => 'https://path-to-autocomplete',
        'tom_select_options' => [
            'create' => false,
            'preload' => true,
            'maxItems' => 1,
            'delimiter' => '/',
        ],
    ])
;
```

The input correctly requests the autocomplete URL, fetches results, renders the correct item label, and sends the correct item value with the form.

The problem arises after submitting the form at step #6.

1. Empty form is rendered.
2. We select an item with ID `15` and label `Foo`.
3. Input is rendered correctly.
4. Form is submitted.
5. Value of `15` is sent to the server with the form.
6. Now we have to re-render a form again with an initial value of the input of `15`.

At this point, the input value is rendered as `15` instead of `Foo`. That makes perfect sense. The input just doesn't know how to get a label for an item with ID `15`.

[image]

Question: how do I provide the input with data about the item label?

I expected the it to have something like `reverse_autocomplete_url` that would be called after input initialization to get items by their IDs but I don't think there is such an option.

Comment: sounds like you need a [DataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#example-2-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the form field with [options array](https://tom-select.js.org/examples/options/):

```
'tom_select_options' => [
    'options' => [
        [
            'value' => 15,
            'text' => 'Foo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

`value` and `text` keys are [customizable](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/) via `valueField` and `labelField` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you used symfony form.

You used `$form->isValid()` etc..

Persisted and flush your object.

Then instead of re-rendering the twig, call `redirectToRoute` function to the current route.

If you provide more detail about your usecase i can give you a better answer.